# Why is 1 + 1 = 0 when we make the addition table for F = {0, 1} (F = field)

Tags: analysis

In Analysis, I learned that any number system satisfying all the axioms (commutativity, associativity, identity elements, invertibility, distributivity) is called a field. Then the professor mentioned that the set {0, 1} = F is also a field.

Then he drew this:
+ 0 1
0 0 1
1 1 0

My question is why is 1 + 1 = 0 in the table? So, if we assumed that the set {0, 1} is a field, then I see that 1 + 1 = 0. But wasn't our purpose to show that the set {0, 1} is a field? Then shouldn't we just perform it "normally" i.e. 1 + 1 = 2? Then since 2 is not in F, we can conclude that this is not a field?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: the additive identity is $0,$ we are not allowed to have $1+1=1.$ So $1+1=0.$

Comment: There are only two elements in $F$, so since $1+1\neq 1, $....

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Here, we are thinking of doing the operations "[mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) 2". Let's look at the field axioms your professor gave:
using the addition table he wrote out, we can show that the addition he defines is commutative, associative, and multiplication distributes over it. As well, with this addition, $1$ is it's own additive inverse. I would check out the modular arithmetic link above to learn more about this, and if you would like to know more about finite fields in general, here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) to the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of a field, by "$0$ or $1$" we don't mean the *numbers* $0$ or $1$, we mean the the elements $0$ or $1$ which are the identity elements for addition and multiplication respectively.

A field, I repeat, need not have numbers in it and $0$ and $1$ should not be interpreted as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you interpret these elements as representing the parity of an integer $o$ for ‘even’,   for ‘odd’, $1+1=0$ just means odd $+$ odd $=$ even.